# Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Tags: postgresql, flask

The error in the subject is encountered when executing the below command.

```
heroku run python manage.py db upgrade
```

```
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

The app works perfectly on local server, but does not migrate to heroku with postgres db.

Have tried countless solutions, nothing has worked yet.

When starting the db, below is the message that comes up

```
aiting for server to start....2020-10-11 20:14:58.637 +04 [11244] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.0 on x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0, compiled by Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.8), 64-bit
2020-10-11 20:14:58.641 +04 [11244] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::1", port 5432
2020-10-11 20:14:58.641 +04 [11244] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2020-10-11 20:14:58.644 +04 [11244] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2020-10-11 20:14:58.672 +04 [11246] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2020-10-11 20:11:13 +04
2020-10-11 20:14:59.020 +04 [11246] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2020-10-11 20:14:59.034 +04 [11246] LOG:  redo starts at 0/1671320
2020-10-11 20:14:59.034 +04 [11246] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/1671358: wanted 24, got 0
2020-10-11 20:14:59.034 +04 [11246] LOG:  redo done at 0/1671320
2020-10-11 20:14:59.067 +04 [11244] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
 done
server started
```

Answer (score 1):

you just need to restart the server's psql. Be carefull with this database:

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

I had the same error all of a sudden. It resolves. It is not related to psycopg2.connect(dsn)

Answer (score -1):

The issue is; from error '"/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?", versus from log "listening on Unix socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432".  First I would try changing your `DSN` to use `host=` so you are not trying to connect to a socket.  Then you need to sort out why  `psycopg2` is looking for different socket. Generally that happens when it is compiled/used against `libpq` on one distribution that puts the socket at `/var/run/` and then run on another where the socket is at `/tmp/`.

Comment: Unless  your dsn for `conn`  is pointing at this it will not work. You need to provide complete information and do so in your question, so others don't have to go through all the comments to find it. Try what I suggested in my answer, which is point `host` at something that is not a socket. In other words at an actual host name or address.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help Adrian, but not able to understand what is required to be done.

Comment: For a start in your question provide the information for what `dsn` in `conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)` is?

Comment: have not set any dsn explicitly on my mac

Comment: Well that is your issue. You need to specify something for `dsn` in `psycopg2.connect(dsn)`, wherever that called in the code. Otherwise it is going to use default values. Also I'm guessing you installed `psycopg2-binary`.

Comment: To get this solved you will need to provide more information in your question. How where you running the application locally? Where exactly is `manage.py` coming from and doing? What are the database settings in your app? The database log is from the local or remote server? Can you connect to the remote server using `psql`?